# Can't unlock cryptswap1

Tags: boot, initramfs, cryptsetup

Today I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10 from Ubuntu 18.04. Unfortunately when everything is done I rebooted the system and I was surprised by this screen.

[image]

I looked everywhere for such a problem but it seems it's a first. And I don't have any encrypted partition.

Comment: You didn't encrypt your swap file?

Comment: You need to boot into a live session and backup then remove that encrypted swapfile and make a new one!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I don't remember

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen How can I remove the swapfile?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I've checked this url, but how can I do that from a live session?

Comment: What url please provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: doing as described *will disable swap encryption*.

To repair this situation as I suspect you might have encrypted your swap file boot from you installation usb or disk and select `Try Ubuntu`, then:

1. Mount your `root` partition:

   ```
   sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdaX /mnt
   ```
2. Chroot into that mount:

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   ```
3. **BACKUP YOUR DATA USING A TOOL LIKE `RSYNC`**
4. Fix the encrypted swapfile:

   1. Remove the swap file entry in the `/etc/crypttab` with `sudo nano /etc/crypttab`, may look something like this:

      ```
      cryptswap1 /swapfile /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,size=256
      ```
   2. Remove Mount point for swap in `/etc/fstab` too.
   3. Make new swap:

      ```
       sudo swapoff /swapfile
       sudo rm -rf /swapfile
       sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024M count=<put_half_the_size_of_RAM>
       sudo mkswap /swapfile
       sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
       sudo swapon  /swapfile
      ```
   4. Add mount for swap at boot:

      ```
      /swapfile      none   swap    sw    0    0
      ```
5. Disengage the mount:

   ```
   exit
   sudo umount /mnt
   ```

Now shutdown and reboot, if you see any errors run `fsck /dev/sdaX`.

#### Notes

- `X` is the partition number for you root file mount `/`.
  For the `dd` command if your RAM is 8G use `count=4` to run that command. To increase your `swap` file size use this `dd` command:

  ```
  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=1024 oflag=append conv=notrunc
  ```

Comment: I had only to remove this line "#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0"  from fstab to make ubuntu boot normally, then I've done what you've posted. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes I forgot that part, apologies

Answer (score 1):

I filed a bug report for this issue in Launchpad (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1802617).